# Basics of Compton scatter interactions? Forces behind it?

Tags: photons, scattering, interactions

What is the force that governs compton scattering interaction? Also how is it that we are able to approximate that compton scattering probability is proportional to the mass density of the target material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the force that governs compton scattering interaction?

[Compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering) is an electromagnetic interaction of photons with charged particles and is modeled and the photon electron probability of scattering is calculated using [Feynman diagrams.](http://inspirehep.net/record/835700/plots)

[image: compt]

> Also how is it that we are able to approximate that compton scattering probability is proportional to the mass density of the target material?

The masses in material are composed of atoms, which have [electron orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) around positive nuclei. The more mass density the more electrons for the photon to interact with a proton scatter, the the statement would hold for X rays which penetrate the bulk, not for visible frequency photons which would interact with the surface electrons.